# Using variadic template to create template class tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to make a variadic template class `postOffice`

```
template <class... AllInputTypes>
class PostOffice {
public:
   PostOffice(AllInputTypes&... akkUboytTypes)
   : allInputMsgStorage(allInputTypes...) {}
...
protected:
   std::tuple<StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>...> allInputMsgStorage; //TODO: Will this work?
}
```

With `StorageSlot`

```
template<class InputMsgType>
class StorageSlot {
public:
    StorageSlot(InputMsgType& input)
    : readFlag(false),
      writeFlag(false),
      storageField(input)
      //TODO initialize timer with period, get period from CAN
    {}
    virtual ~StorageSlot();
    InputMsgType storageField; //the field that it is being stored into
    bool readFlag; //the flag that checks if it is being read into
    bool writeFlag; //flag that checks if it is being written into
    Timer StorageSlotTimer; //the timer that checks the read and write flag
};
```

So in the tuple, I'm trying to initialize a tuple of

```
StorageSlot<AllInputType1>, StorageSlot<AllInputType2>,...
```

etc

Will this work? I've tried

```
std::tuple<StorageSlot<AllInputTypes...>> allInputMsgStorage;
```

But this creates a mismatch between the variadic template and the single template storage slot. However, I'm not sure IF

```
std::tuple<StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>...> allInputMsgStorage;
```

is defined at all (`StorageSlot` is not a template), let alone produce the right results. The only reason I can think of getting this work is having the `StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>` directly send to the `postOffice`, and do

```
std::tuple<AllInputTypeStorageSlots...> allInputMsgStorage;
```

which makes the template interface of the `PostOffice` class kinda ugly

So will this work, and if not, how could I get this to work?

Comment: Have you come across any problems in compiling or running the program? It looks like this should work fine.

Comment: `StorageSlot` of course is a template. `StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>` will expand just fine.

Comment: It compiles, but I have not yet been able to find a way to test whether this gives the right behavior. But I'm mostly curious on how the compiler would interpret 'std::tuple<StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>...> allInputMsgStorage;'. How does the compiler determine that the '...' refers to the variadic 'AllInputTypes', and that it should give 1 element of the variadic template to each StorageSlot tuple member?

Comment: Is there any literature on how the compiler will tackle this? Pick the first element of the variadic template (as StorageSlot only requires one), then pass the rest of the variadic template on to the rest of the tuple or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general concept is correct - with a little polish, the constructors can be given perfect forwarding for better efficiency.

In addition, no virtual destructor is necessary in StorageSlot - always use the rule of zero unless you're going to be using dynamic polymorphism:

compilable code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

struct Timer
{};

template<class InputMsgType>
class StorageSlot {
public:

    template<class ArgType>
    StorageSlot(ArgType&& input)
        : readFlag(false),
        writeFlag(false),
        storageField(std::forward<ArgType>(input))
    //TODO initialize timer with period, get period from CAN
    {}

    InputMsgType storageField; //the field that it is being stored into
    bool readFlag; //the flag that checks if it is being read into
    bool writeFlag; //flag that checks if it is being written into
    Timer StorageSlotTimer; //the timer that checks the read and write flag
};


template <class... AllInputTypes>
class PostOffice {
public:

    //
    // note - perfect forwarding
    //
    template<class...Args>
    PostOffice(Args&&... allInputTypes)
    : allInputMsgStorage(std::forward<Args>(allInputTypes)...)
    {

    }

protected:
    std::tuple<StorageSlot<AllInputTypes>...> allInputMsgStorage; //TODO: Will this work? - yes
};





int main()
{
    PostOffice<int, double, std::string> po(10, 20.1, "foo");

}
```